# High Creatinine level in female Dalmatian

Tags: dogs, health

I have a Dalmatian Female who is 11 years and 9 months old. Recently she started vomiting. All the tests were done and her Creatinine Serum is 2.8 mg/dl & Potassium Serum is 5.94 mEq/l. She has been getting saline/DNS since 31st December 2018. The level has not come down.

From the 21st of January 2019, we have started her on AZODYL 2 capsules in the morning and 1 in the evening. She was put on renal food which she dislikes. Since yesterday she is dull, not eating food and there is swelling in her leg. The doctors were talking in terms of Dialysis.

Can you suggest what should be done?